# Error: the preLaunchTask build terminated with exit code -1, launch program does not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vscode

Recientemente he estado intentando mudarme de CodeBlocks a Visual Studio Code, pero este ultimo me ha estado dando problemas sobre todo cuando hago proyectos con clases, en este caso al intentar correr aparece esto:

[image: Lo primero que aparece]

Después me aparece este error:

[image: Segundo error]

Estos son los *launch.json* y *task.json* que tengo:

**launch.json:**

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myfile.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true
    },
    {
        "name": "(Windows) Attach",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]
```

}

**tasks.json:**

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build myfile",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-std=c++14",
            "-g",
            "-o",
            "myfile.exe",
            "myfile.cpp"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
]
```

}

Todos los .json los saque de esta respuesta que pensé me ayudaría pero no afecto en nada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658089/19009898

*Se apreciaría bastante la ayuda.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedo ver que la tarea de compilación se limita al archivo que tienes abierto.

Debido a los errores que muestra el terminal, intuyo que también tienes más de un archivo `.cpp`.

Cuando este es el caso (código en varios archivos `.cpp`), necesitas indicar cada uno de ellos como parámetro.

Supon que tu código está en los archivos `a.cpp` y `b.cpp`. Para compilarlo correctamente lo haces así: `g++ a.cpp b.cpp -o programa.exe`.

Para no tener que indicar todos los archivos manualmente puedes modificar la tarea para que compile todos los que estén en la carpeta del archivo abierto. Como sugiere [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236875/13419694):

```
"label": "g++.exe build active file",
"args": [
    "-g",
    "${fileDirname}\\**.cpp",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
]
```